# How to create a form in Rails that adds information to multiple tables in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on an application where during the registration process users must enter information such as the following:

- e-mail
- password
- company
- package (the user would select a package from a list)

In my database, I have a table for users, companies, and packages (a separate table for each).

How do I make sure that the information from the "User Registration Form" goes to separate tables in the database? To be more specific, how does the single registration form (1) adds the user's e-mail and password to the "Users" table & (2) adds the company name to the "Companies" table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for :packages`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) in your User model. Then you can use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) in your view to allow package info to be submitted from the user form.

If you need a more in depth example of how to use nested forms, have a google around. I believe railscasts has a good tutorial for it.